# Is there any direct method which returns the sum of lengths of arrays in the array of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects and I want to find the sum of length of arrays of a certain property(key).
I have this array of objects like

```
var myArray = 
[{
    "a" : 1,
    "b" : another Array
},
{
    "c" : 2,
    "b" : another Array
}
.....
]
```

Is there any way to simplify this below process?

```
var lengthOfEachObject = myArray.map(function(Obj){

    if(Obj.b){
       return Obj.b.length;
    }
    else{
       return 0;
    } 
});
lengthofEachObject.reduce(function(x,y){
    return x+y;
})
```

Answers can also include use of external libraries.

Comment: Looks like you already have the best solution, which I was about to propose.

Comment: so you want to find the total length of all arrays which fall under the value of `b` in all your objects?

Comment: I am just looking for any other simple methods to simplify the above process

Comment: You don't need `.map()` for this. `return x + (y.b ? y.b.length : 0);`

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah You're right

Comment: @Andreas `.map` or `.forEach` would do right, you definitely have to loop over the whole array or object.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yes, but one round with `.reduce()` is enough

Comment: @Andreas Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) without `.map`, this way you can get the total sum by only iterating once over your array. Furthermore, you can use [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) instead of your `if` statements to set a default value for your `b.length` if it doesn't exist.

See working example below:

```js
const arr = [{a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, {c: 2, b: [1, 2, 3]}, {e: 3}],
total = arr.reduce((acc, {b={length:0}}) => acc + b.length, 0);

console.log(total);
```

Comment: Dude, you are 30 seconds faster than me. LoL. Good one.

Comment: There seems to be the chance that there's no `b` property. Otherwise the explicit `if(Obj.b){...}` wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I'm looking for other methods if any for doing this.

Comment: @Andreas ah, I see, should be fixed now

Comment: @RahulMathews what do you mean by other methods? This is different to the code you provided

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash's [`_.sumBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sumBy):

```js
var myArray = [{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3]},{"c":2,"b":[4,5,6,7,8]},{"c":2}]

var result = _.sumBy(myArray, 'b.length')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pull out the length with a closure over the wanted key and map this value.

```js
const
    length = k => ({ [k]: { length = 0 } = {} }) => length,
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    array = [{ a: 1, b: [1, 2, 3, 4] }, { c: 2, b: [1, 2, 3] }];
    
console.log(array.map(length('b')).reduce(add));
console.log(array.map(length('a')).reduce(add));
```